# how to make salt-minion generate new keys

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am playing around with salt and what my problem is launching instance from Amazon EC2 AMI results minion keys being the same. How do I refresh individual minion to get it's new identity (key)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Stop the minion service.

   ```
   service salt-minion stop
   ```
2. Delete old identity

   ```
   rm /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
   rm /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub
   cat /dev/null > /etc/salt/minion_id
   ```
3. Make sure salt will begin on startup

   ```
   chkconfig salt-minion on
   ```
4. Create your a new AMI

Answer (score 4):

Give the following command a try:

```
sudo salt 'name_of_host_whose_keys_you_wish_to_regenerate' saltutil.regen_keys
```

Source: 
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.saltutil.html#salt.modules.saltutil.regen_keys

Comment: What if I need to generate keys bc the salt 'broadcast' doesn't work yet?

Answer (score 1):

Based on user325017's answer.

I adapted this for Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04, since it has systemd:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

systemctl stop salt-minion
rm /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
rm /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub
cat /dev/null > /etc/salt/minion_id
systemctl enable salt-minion
systemctl start salt-minion
```

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 10 and possibly others, the files have changed location.
Do this:

```
# Stop the service.
service salt-minion stop

# Delete key files.
rm /var/lib/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub
rm /var/lib/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem

# Edit minion_id to the desired name you want to appear in saltstack.
# Or you can rm this file and the minion will create it containing the hostname. 
vi /etc/salt/minion_id

# Start the service.
service salt-minion start
```

Answer (score -1):

Following @user325017 answer for Windows, tweak step 2 with:

Remove C:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pem
Remove C:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pub
Edit c:\salt\conf\minion, and update the line with "id:"

Comment: This should be a comment to the answer you're referring to.